# Python - How to unpack a string?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a specific case, i need to unpack a list of strings into a 'variables'.
The strings contain a code which is filtering the dataframe that i get from another API.
The strings looks something like this:

```
example_string = "Data[Data['Number'] > 2]"
example_string_2 = "Data[Data['Length'] <= 15]"
```

What i need to do is to treat these strings like a filtered dataframes. So in other words i need these string values to work as a normal code.

I tried to unpack these with using the asterisk, fe. *example_string but it is not really working.

Comment: You should use `ast.literal_eval` from the `ast` module.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal That's not gonna do much here, those strings aren't literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on exactly what the syntax of those expressions are, [`pandas.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) might be the thing for you:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Number': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'Length':  [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]})

ld = {'Data': df}
print(pd.eval("Data[Data['Number'] > 2]", local_dict=ld))
print(pd.eval("Data[Data['Length'] <= 15]", local_dict=ld))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps

```
example_string  = 't1 = ' + example_string    # add variables where you can see result
exec(example_string)
example_string_2 = 't2 = ' + example_string_2 
exec(example_string_2)
print(t1, t2)
```

Comment: Using exec is likely to be a bad idea due to [security concerns](https://realpython.com/python-exec/). Running exec on untrusted strings is a great way to get your app pwned.